# How to set Ipv4 addresses with dbus-python (Hotspot and ethernet)

Tags: dbus, dhcp, networkmanager, nmcli, dbus-python

(fairly new to networking)

I'm trying to setup a small, yet somewhat complicated network settings on my ubuntu 18.04 machine.

The topology of the network: Ubuntu machine (called "the server") will act as the DHCP server for both hotspot and ethernet. connected to the ubuntu machine are 2 ubuntu machine clients and a camera.

I've implemented "the server" with python-dbus library, to set up/down a hotspot connection, which works as intended. but my problem is how to manage the ip addresses and the routing.

i'll elaborate on 2 problems i am facing:

1. in order to change the ipv4 address for the Hotspot AP, i found out i could edit a file: "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/", adding another line: "address1=X.Y.Z.W" (my desired ip address).

but editing the file isn't the proper way for my requirements, i would rather do it from the code itself. which changes do i need to make to the code in order to make the same changes?

this is how the code connection object of dbus looks like:

```
def get_hotspot_struct(iface, uuid, ssid, password):
    s_con = dbus.Dictionary({
        'type': '802-11-wireless',
        'uuid': uuid,
        'id': 'PixellotHotspot',
        'interface-name': iface,
    })

    s_wifi = dbus.Dictionary({
        'ssid': dbus.ByteArray(ssid.encode()),
        'mode': 'ap',
        'band': 'bg',
        'channel': dbus.UInt32(1),
    })

    s_wsec = dbus.Dictionary({
        'key-mgmt': 'wpa-psk',
        'psk': password,
    })

    s_ipv4 = dbus.Dictionary({
        'method': 'shared',
    })

    s_ipv6 = dbus.Dictionary({
        'method': 'ignore',
    })

    con = dbus.Dictionary({
        'connection': s_con,
        '802-11-wireless': s_wifi,
        '802-11-wireless-security': s_wsec,
        'ipv4': s_ipv4,
        'ipv6': s_ipv6,
    })

    logger.info('Getting hotspot connection template')
    logger.info(con)

    return con
```

2. Can i do the same for ethernet wired connections?
   so far what ive figured is that I can edit "/etc/netplan/01-netconf.yaml" in order to set dhcp to false, and se an ip "X.Y.Z.W" (desired) for ethernet interface eth0.

but that seem to only work on the server, when i connect the ubuntu clients with ethernet wire to the server, the server wont give the clients any ip at all.
It does for the hotspot, but not for the ethernet.

I know my problem is very specific and all-over-the-place, but i would appreciate any help. Post here/sendme email/ Facebook me(Yves Halimi) if you have knowledge about this issue. Will compensate help!!

Answer (score 0):

The D-Bus API is documented in `man nm-settings-dbus`.

To NetworkManager, it's always about creating connection profiles and activating them. So if you have code that can create one profile, another profile works basically the same -- just some keys will be different.

I find it helpful to use one of the other NetworkManager clients, and compare with what they do. For example, you could also just create the profile with `nmcli connection add type ...`, then get the D-Bus path via `nmcli -f all connection show` and finally, look at how the profiles looks on D-Bus:

```
busctl -j call org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1 org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.Connection GetSettings
```

---

See examples upstream: [python+dbus](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/tree/c391162a81fe72e33ca3e58ec4dad55fa9e0c542/examples/python/dbus)

Maybe you'll find it easier to use python + pygobject + libnm. In that case, see examples [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/tree/c391162a81fe72e33ca3e58ec4dad55fa9e0c542/examples/python/gi). The main downside is that you'll have an additional dependency (pygobject). libnm isn't an additional dependency, you'll already have that if you use NetworkManager.